# Obtaining the expected value $E[X_{(1)} \mid\overline X = c]$

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, sufficient-statistics, rao-blackwell

Suppose we have $X_1,\dots, X_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = 1)$, for a known $n$. And we want to calculate $E[X_{(1)} \mid \overline X = c]$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is known, $X_{(1)}$ is the first order statistic of the $X_i$'s and $\overline X$ is the sample mean of the data.

What I can see is that $X_{(1)}$ is an estimator of the data, because is an order statistic. Also, $X_{(1)}$ is a sufficient statistic of the data, for the same reason. Then, this expected value is really similar to the Rao-Blackwell Theorem to me, but how can I get/calculate this conditional expected value? Shouldn't one of the parameters ($\mu$, $\sigma^2$) need to be unknown to apply Rao-Blackwell?

Also, since $X_{(1)} = \min(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, the expected value would be $E[\min(X_1, \dots, X_n) \mid \overline X] = E[X_1 \leq x, \dots, X_n \leq x\mid \overline X]$?

Comment: Sufficiency has to do with a parameter or parameters. You have a known distribution so there is no parameter to estimate. I don't know what you mean by a sufficient statistic for the data. Since the sample mean equals c under the conditioning you already know that the minimum of the sequence is <= to c. I think you mean to condition on X bar = c We know that the minimum is <=x if & only if all the $X_i$ are <= x.. But you are using it in the expectation incorrectly..

Comment: I think that is where my misconception is, I'm seeing E[X_(1)} | X bar] as defined in the Rao-Blackwell Theorem (θ∗ =E (ˆθ | T), where ˆθ is an estimator and T is a sufficient statistic.)

Comment: The difference is that $X$$_($$_1$$_)$ is not a parameter of the population distribution it's a function of the sample and it's not a sufficient statistic for an unknown parameter of the population distribution.

Comment: Then, for example in this case, I could get $P(X_{(1)} \leq x)$, which if I didn't made a mistake should be $1 - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}) e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)^2}$. And then, I can get the $E[X_{(1)} | \bar{X}]$ from the definition of expectation?

Comment: In the formula you need to replace $\mu$ with 0 & $\sigma^2$ with 1. Also the normal density needs to be integrate from -$\infinity$ to $x$.

Comment: I tried to edit the previous comment to say "integrate from - infinity to $x$."  So the probability that the minimum of the $X_i$s is less than or equal to $x$ is F($x$)$^n$ where F($x$) is the cumulative standard normal distribution at $x$. This is not the formula you gave.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you go from that to get the conditional expectation you are trying to compute.

Comment: My idea was that once I have $P(X_{(1)}|\bar{X})$, I could use $\int X_{(1)} P(X_{(1)} | \bar{X}) dx$.

Comment: That is the right idea. But remember that you are conditioning on the sample mean being equal to c. So you have to figure out the appropriate region of integration. Remember that the minimum of the $X_i$ has to be <c when the sample mean=c.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $N(\theta,1)$ where $\theta\in \mathbb R$.

Then $\overline X$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Note that $X_{(1)}-\overline X=(X_{(1)}-\theta)-(\overline X-\theta)$, so that its distribution is free of $\theta$.

By [Basu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem), the ancillary statistic $X_{(1)}-\overline X$ is independent of $\overline X$.

Therefore,

$$E\left[X_{(1)}-\overline X\right]=E\left[X_{(1)}-\overline X\mid \overline X\right]=E\left[X_{(1)}\mid \overline X\right]-\overline X$$

So for every $\theta$, we must have

$$E\left[X_{(1)}\mid \overline X\right]=E\left[X_{(1)}-\overline X\right]+ \overline X=E\left[X_{(1)}\right]-\theta+\overline X$$

In particular, the above holds for $\theta=0$.

Comment: Since $E[X_{(1)}]=c+\theta$ where $c$ is the expectation of the first order statistic from $N(0,1)$, the conditional expectation is always free of $\theta$.